# How to set the image quality while converting a canvas with the "toDataURL" method?

Tags: javascript, image, html5-canvas, png, jpeg

I want to set the quality factor when I encode a canvas element to jpg.

```
var data = myCanvas.toDataURL( "image/jpeg" );
```

It does not give me a quality option.  Is there an alternative library I can use?

Related: what is the default quality setting used by the different browsers?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

The second argument of the function is the quality. It ranges from 0.0 to 1.0

```
canvas.toDataURL(type,quality);
```

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLCanvasElement#Methods) you have extended information

And I don't think it's possible to know the quality of the image once is converted. As you can see on this [feedle](http://jsfiddle.net/Wc26H/1/) the only information you get when printing the value on the console is the type and the image code itself.

Here's a snippet of code I made to know the default value of the quality used by the browser.

```
    var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.fillStyle="#FF0000";
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,150,75);

    var url = c.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
    var v = 0
    for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++ ){

        v += 0.01;
        x = parseFloat((v).toFixed(2))
        var test = c.toDataURL('image/jpeg', x);

        if(test == url){
            console.log('The default value is: ' + x);
        }
    }
```

Basically I thought that the change on the image itself would be reflected on the base64 string. So the code just try all the possible values on the `toDataURL()` method and compares the resulting string with the default one. And it seems to work. For chromium I get 0.92.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/ZHR6N/) is the working example on a fiddle.

Comment: The default value on firefox also is 0.92

Comment: 0.92 on Chrome 32 too.

Answer (score 7):

Using [Fabric.js](http://fabricjs.com/), a very simple and human-readable way, is this:

```
canvas.toDataURL({
   format: 'jpeg',
   quality: 0.8
});
```

This also allows you to have other options, giving you the ability to crop the image, etc:

```
canvas.toDataURL({
    format: 'png',
    left: 300,
    top: 250,
    width: 200,
    height: 150
})
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7f9bqs00/30/

Comment: I want to update the url to the example to http://jsfiddle.net/7f9bqs00/30/ . The original jsFiddle example url is http://jsfiddle.net/fabricjs/NfZVb/. I updated the CDN lib, made the export examples more descriptive & meaningful. Furtermore I added buttons for interactivity.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for improving quality for canvas.toDataUrl() in fabricJS for format: 'png' then use property 'multiplier' for the same. This is specific for PNG format only. Please checkout the below code

```
 const dataURL = canvas.toDataURL({
    width: canvas.width,
    height: canvas.height,
    left: 0,
    top: 0,
    format: "png",
    multiplier: 2
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const fullQuality = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 1.0);
const mediumQuality = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 0.5);
const lowQuality = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 0.1);

// output: data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQ…9oADAMBAAIRAxEAPwD/AD/6AP/Z"
```

[Setting image quality with jpegs | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL#setting_image_quality_with_jpegs)