# canvas.drawImage() increases the size of the image

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas

```
var crop_canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
crop_canvas.width = rcWidth;
crop_canvas.height = rcHeight;
crop_canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(image_target, rcLeft, rcTop, rcWidth, rcHeight, 0, 0, rcWidth, rcHeight);
```

`image_target` is having the image element

`rcLeft`: x coordinate for cropping

`rcTop`: y coordinate for cropping

`rcWidth`: width of cropped image

`rcHeight`: height of cropped image

Considering we do not need to crop the image, we just need a copy of the image.

The copy created is of greater size ie.If the image is of 1MB. The copy created is of 5MB approx.

Comment: How do you measure the size of an image on a canvas in MB?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14383557/setting-canvas-todataurl-jpg-quality

Comment: Because canvas data is uncompressed row pixels, while your image is compressed (either through jpeg (lossy compression) or png (lossless compression))

Comment: Ps: why do you need a copy of the image, where does the source comes from?

Comment: I need to crop the image, but when tried cropping the full image, come to know what the size is increased

Comment: @nnnnnn With the help of blob

Comment: "*Considering we do not need to crop the image, we just need a copy of the image.*" Do you need to crop it or not ? You can already reduce the size of your output by using the `toBlob(callback, 'image/jpeg', quality)`, where `quality` is a 0-1 float, but you'll loose in image quality though.

Comment: I have provided the ability to crop the image, but there can be a case the user needs the uncropped image or cropping only 2-3 pixels and I don't wanna use quality as it is somewhat near 0.92 in chrome I think and that is best-suited for it. Quality too is to be maintained

Comment: For the 2-3 px it's impossible. Since one can give you a jpeg image, already deteriored with jpeg artifacts, and compressed, you can't uncompress it, draw it on a canvas and export at the same size. You need to compress it again, which means more artifacts. For the no action, just return the original file.

Comment: @Kaiido it was really not meant 2-3 pixels only. It can be 100 or more but the fact is, the size of the image is considered wrong. If we take a part of 1 MB image and canvas is cropping it from more than that. It's obvious, there is something left behind which causes the increase in the image size

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_compression canvas data is uncompressed. Your original image is compressed. Canvas compression algorithms are limited. Once uncompressed, you can't retrieve the original size of a lossy compressed image without losing more quality. That's it. End of the story.